# Git not using user.name

Tags: linux, git, configuration, git-commit

I am logged into a Linux system via SSH as user `bob` and I have

```
$ git config --list --show-origin
file:/home/bob/.gitconfig     user.name=Robert DaBuilder
file:/home/bob/.gitconfig     user.email=robert.dabuilder@buildingsite.com
file:/home/bob/.gitconfig     color.ui=auto
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.symlinks=false
```

When I commit something, I get:

```
$ git commit -m "Add further text"
[master ad1cd5e] Add further text
Author: bob <robert.dabuilder@buildingsite.com>
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
```

So in the 'Author' field, why is my login name `bob` being used and not `user.name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git uses environment varible `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` as primary source of information, if it's not set then use config value.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find the information here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.  It seems a bit unfortunate that ```GIT_AUTHOR_NAME``` overrides all other settings but is not shown by  ```git config --list --show-origin```.  Or is there another command which will do that?

Comment: Do you mean a command which shows the value of `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` as well ?
I'm not aware of that.